# How can i get the Max number in my SQL query

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, ssms

I'm trying to write a query That return the max number of guest that rode any ride. Essentially the most popular ride. I Want to return both the number of guest that ride had and the Ride ID as well. I Feel like this is a simple task but i just started in SQL so any help would be useful

```
select MAX(Count(distinct GuestID)), RideID 
from GUEST_RIDES
Where RideDate between '2016-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'
```

Answer (score 2):

My approach would be.

```
select top 1 rideid
, count(distinct guestID) riders
from guest_rides
Where RideDate between '2016-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'
group by rideId
order by riders desc
```

Comment: WOW thanks that did it...do you mind explaining it to me ? it's nice to get it but is even better to understand it